# How is the `flash` in Rails made global to an application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm curious as to how Rails achieves this. I notice that you can access the `flash` variable globally in an app, but it isn't prefixed with an `@` or a `$`.

I can also see that there's a method for accessing the [`flash`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb#L8) and there's also an [initializer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb#L51) as well that will set `@flash`, but how is it that I can call `flash` as a local variable?

Comment: its not global, its attached to the env and delegated to it from views and controllers

Comment: And can you show me how that is done in an answer please?

Comment: There isn't a method for accessing `flash`, `flash` *is* a method. Just like `session`, `params`, `cookies`, ... are methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Session**

Further to `apneadiving`'s answer, the `flash` is part of the middleware stack ([`ActionDispatch::Flash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html)). It's actually a non-persistent `session` cookie:

--

From [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash):

> The flash is a special part of the session which is cleared with each
>   request. This means that values stored there will only be available in
>   the next request, which is useful for passing error messages etc.

Much in the same way that `params` works (on a per request basis), the `flash` variable is only populated with data from the previous request.

--

**Middleware**

If you take *apneadiving*'s comment, you'll see that the `flash` is created through the `middleware` stack - meaning the local nature of the variable is only set for that particular request (much the same as `params`). This is why you can access / set a `flash` message in any controller - because it's defined higher up the "middleware stack" - it provides a scope which appears global

I'm sure someone like *apneadiving* can explain it better than me, but that's how I see it